# Calculating number of possible password combinations given specific assumptions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am trying to calculate the number of possible password combinations, but with specific assumptions.

These are my assumptions:

- The password contains one word that is 8 characters in length
- The first character of this word is uppercase. It is **always** the first character, nowhere else.
- There is a single number and a single special character at the end of the password.

  - **Numbers**: only the numbers 1, 2, 3 can be used
  - **Special Characters**: only the special characters !, ?, $, #, @, *, &, ^, % can be used
- The number and special character must be at the end of the password, but can be in any order

  - For example, the number can come before the character, or the character before the number

So, an example password may be: **Bookworm2$** or **Icecream!1**

My current attempt is as follows:

- 26 possible uppercase characters
- 26^7 lowercase characters (in any order)
- 3 possible numbers
- 9 possible special characters

Becoming: **26 + (26^7) + (3 * 9 * 2)**, which is 8,031,810,256 different combinations.

I am looking to seek confirmation that this is correct, and if not what I need to do to correct it.

Comment: Your choices for the first position, the middle seven positions, and the last two positions are independent.  Therefore, you should multiply rather than add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First letter is always uppercase thus you have $26$ options for it.
Then, we know it is the prefix of a word of length $8$ thus we need to complete it by choosing $7$ lowercased letters:

$$ \overbrace{26}^{\text{uppercase}} \cdot \overbrace{26^7}^{\text{lowercase}} = 26^8$$

Then we need to end the password by choosing a place for the special character or the number, choosing one position immediately reveals the position of the other - thus the total number of options for them is:

$$ \binom{2}{1} \binom{9}{1}  \binom{3}{1} = 54$$

We need to then multiply everything together and get:

$$ 26^8 \cdot 54 $$

As for every single choice we have a new password to "complete", for example, if we choose $B$ over $D$ to be the first letter, we have all the sub-passwords that begin with $D$ (we then complete the password for each choice) In other words every choice is independent.

Comment: The way I read the rules, the digit and the special character must be in the last two positions.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear - the word itself should be 8 characters (including the uppercase character), not the entire password. Also, N. F. Taussig is correct, the digit and special character must be in the last two positions.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I did miss that, sorry, I will delete and edit again.